# AdMob best practice : Should i request a Ad banner of AdMob on each page or only on first page of my mobile application

Tags: angular, admob, ionic3, ionic-native, cordova-admob

In my mobile application, i request a Ad banner of AdMob on first page only. Now this Ad banner is sticked for all pages. 
Is this a good practice or should i request a new banner on every page to increase the number of Impressions and revenue.

**Current Implementation**

**app.component.ts**

> ```
> constructor(platform: Platform, private admob: AdMobPro){
>    platform.ready().then(() => {
>      this.showBanner();
>    });
> }
>
> showBanner() {
>    this.admob.createBanner({adId: 'xyz', isTesting: true, autoShow: true})
>              .then(() => this.admob.showBanner(this.admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER));
> }
> ```

If i create the banner here, it will get stick to all pages.

*Should i write the same code for all the pages of my application, so that a new banner request is made on every page to increase the number of Impressions and revenue.*

Comment: Can you show some `code` of your implementation?

Comment: @Sampath Sorry, i didn't notice your comment. Now I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Are you using `adMob free` or `pro`?

Comment: I'm using admob pro

Comment: Can you tell me why you have chosen `Pro` instead of `Free`?

Comment: @Sampath I wanted to use some custom size banners on some pages. So, i decided to go with **admob pro**. Even if it is **admob free**, should i request a new banner on each page of my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done it correctly. No need to implement this on each and every page. Google doesn't care about the way it has been developed on the app.They'll pay according to the [**eCPM**](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3418058?ctx=ui&hl=en) and `Paid per click` methods.

Payment from `impressions` was negligible.So most of the revenue you'll receive through `Paid per click` ads.

Here you can see the [**AdMob Banner Ads Best Practices**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTnqcz6RJ-4).